# Is reducer bottleneck in MR framework

Tags: mapreduce, out-of-memory, hadoop2, reducers

I want to understand what to do in the following case.
For example, I have 1TB of text data, and lets assume that 900GB of it is the word "Hello".
After each map operation, i will have a collection of key-value pairs of <"Hello",1>.

But as I said, this is a huge collection, 900GB and as I understand , the reducer gets all of it and will crush.

My reducer RAM is of 80GB only.

Will the **reducer** **really** crush ?? 
In other words is **reducer** the **bottleneck** of horizontal scaling ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all equal keys from all mappers get funneled into a single reducer.

It's not clear if you have 900GB of only one word, or a bunch of large text documents with a bunch of words.

In the later case, the string "Hello" really doesn't take that much data. Neither does a single integer.

The reducer will also get a long list of ones, sure, but if you re-used the reducer code as a Combiner, then you can mitigate the memory issues by pre-aggregating the values for each input split